# Mongo Compass Can't Connect to my Server. NodeJS and shell works

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDb server setup on my server.
When i start my nodeJs application on it it works perfectly, i can also view and edit my db using the shell when im connected via ssh.
It also used to work with mongo Compass, then a few days suddenly i couldn't connect to my db using compass anymore. Shell and nodeJs connections are still working tho.
I Am getting The Error `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`
After a Bit looking around an i read a article stating i should look at the log at /var/log/mongodb/mongobd.log

This is The Output from The log, when im trying to connect via ssh. I've already confirmed that this entry is mongo compass trying to connect by restarting and shutting down every service which is using mongodb.

```
2020-05-03T21:26:19.575+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:33694 #5 (3 connections now open)
2020-05-03T21:26:49.689+0000 I NETWORK  [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:33694 (2 connections now open)
```